# Implementation of custom loss function invariant to batch size

Tags: keras, tensorflow, loss-function

When Implementing custom loss function how to make it invariant to the `batch size`. For example lets say `dice loss` is being implemented. The formula for `dice loss` is:
$$
\sum_{c}{} 1 - {DSC}_{c}\\
c: \text{Classes},\hspace{5mm} {DSC}_{c}: \text{Dice score of class }c
$$

This formula does not clarify how to deal with the `batch size`. It is worth noting that according to this formula, the value of `loss` will increase if the `batch size` is increased. The obvious intuition would be to normalize the `loss` value using `batch size`. I have two question in this context.

1. Is it theoretically valid to normalize the `loss` using the `batch size`?
2. How to normalize?

- For example, In case of image the `tensor` at hand is `4D`. The `dice score` / `loss` can be calculated for *each image* and *each class* resulting into a `2D` tensor like below, where $n$ is no. of classes and $m$ is the `batch size`.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
l_{1, 1} & \dots & l_{1, n}\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
l_{m, 1} & \dots & l_{m, n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
      Now the aggregated `loss` can be calculated as:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} l_{i, j} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m} l_{i, j}
$$

- Alternatively, we can ignore the `batch size` from the beginning and generate per class `loss` in a `1D` `tensor`:
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  l_{1}^{'} & \dots & l_{n}^{'}
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$

Accordingly, the normalized aggregated `loss` will be:

$$
\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{n} l_{k}^{'}
$$

**Is there any fundamental difference between these two approaches? Which one is correct (if any)?**

- Related Discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/issues/22)